# Why is strerror_s() with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY error code returning "Exec format error"

Tags: c, windows, error-handling, malloc, strerror

Given the following example C code snippet test case;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define SMALL_BUFFER 256

int main()
{

char* cErrorMessage = malloc(sizeof(char) * SMALL_BUFFER);

if (cErrorMessage == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory available\n");  
    return 1;
}
else
{
    strerror_s(cErrorMessage, SMALL_BUFFER, ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);                                             
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", cErrorMessage);                                                                         
}

free(cErrorMessage);

return 0;
}
```

Why would strerror_s() with the error code ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY return a message of "Exec format error"?

What have I tried? I have read through the documentation for [strerror_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strerror-s-strerror-s-wcserror-s-wcserror-s?view=msvc-170) and [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) to try and figure out what is going on beneath the code.

What I was expecting? I was expecting to see an error message along the lines of "*Not enough memory resources are available to process this command*".

Comment: See ENOEXEC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=msvc-170

Comment: `strerror` and similar functions expect an error number you would get from `errno`, not a Windows system error number. Citing [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-): *"To retrieve the description text for the error in your application, use the `FormatMessage` function with the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` is a Windows-specific error code, usually returned by [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror), while [`strerror` (and `strerror_s`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) deals with standard C error code from `errno` (and on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS is also the standard way to get error codes).

To get descriptions of Windows error code you need to use [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage):

```
char *cErrorMessage = NULL;
FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
               NULL,
               ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY,
               0,
               (LPCSTR) &cErrorMessage,
               0,
               0);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", cErrorMessage);
LocalFree((HLOCAL) cErrorMessage);
```